# Apt installs different package from what I specified

Tags: apt, python, python3

I have both Python 3.6 and 3.7 installed on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine and I am trying to install `python-tk` for Python 3.7. If the package is installed with

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

`python3-tk:amd64 (3.6.8-1~18.04)` version is installed. If the Python version is more specific, apt will still install `python3-tk` which is for Python 3.6:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3.7-tk
[...]
Note, selecting 'python3-tk' instead of 'python3.7-tk'
```

So my question is: How can I force apt to install the version I need?

Comment: Trying to 'force apt' is rarely wise. Your fundamental problem is that you want to run new software on an old release of Ubuntu. Ubuntu is not designed to work that way - newer software is in newer releases. On 19.04, for example, the default Python3 is 3.7, and the 3.7 version of python3-tk installs automatically and easily.